# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in json

Tags: php, json, warnings, file-get-contents

getting a error on file_get_content it is replacing & to `&amp;` hence i am getting d error. data which i am getting is in json format.

original url is: **xyz.abc.com/index.php/DeviceDetails/GetDeviceHistory?tracking_id=70&start_time=2017-03-05 13:14:50&end_time=2017-03-08 13:14:50**

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://xyz.abc.com/index.php/DeviceDetails/GetDeviceHistory?tracking_id=70&amp;start_time=2017-03-05 13:14:50&amp;end_time=2017-03-08 13:14:50): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
     in
    <b>/home/abc/public_html/php/service.php</b> on line
    <b>1855</b>
    <br />
    {"Status":"false","message":"No data found"}
```

please help me with this error

Comment: Can you give more information about your project  or code something?

Comment: Its only replace `&` with `&amp;` in the error message. There is not enough information in this question for us to be any help

Comment: _No data found_ Try another date range

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is my code  $tracking_id = $_REQUEST['sharedid'];
        $start_time = $_REQUEST['start_time'];
        $end_time = $_REQUEST['end_time'];
        
        $url = "http://xyz.abc.com/index.php/DeviceDetails/GetDeviceHistory?tracking_id=$tracking_id&start_time=$start_time&end_time=$end_time";
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
 $restvm = json_decode($result,true);

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am getting result with & but file_get_contents is changing & into &amp;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actual URL is **starting** with **http://** or **https://** and use quotes while calling file_get_contents

file_get_contents("http://your_URL_here")

Answer (score 0):

Try running PHP html_entity_decode() on your URL before you pass it to file_get_contents(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php (as Kuldeep Singh says above, be sure you are passing the URL as a string :D)

I have had many many many problems similar to this. It could be a number of things, a missing header, invalid user agent, bad php.ini config, etc.

I would highly recommend using a cURL Library that allows you to customize headers, port, etc. of the request so you can properly debug. This is the custom PHP cURL library I use: https://gist.github.com/schwindy/e5798405d0b6269945bdf037a58f6a4d

Hope some of that helps. Good luck.